# Cron application nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently using Cronjobs to do some server-side scheduling.

However, I need to implement a graphic interface to it for me to handle, add and delete old tasks. What is the best way to do that?

I am not looking for a direct anwser but ideas on how to implement that.

Comment: https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron I use this library. You can start / stop cron jobs. So I am guessing it would be easy map data from some source into crons

Answer (score 0):

What you basically saying is that you require a front end for your cron jobs. Like any other responsive front end you need to build a GUI then parse the info into your node service via json or Ajax. Use express and pick it up on a route. Should be fairly easy as there is not an overabundance of complicated info to pass on. Though crons can get complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to completly separate the two process, and do the link with a database, it will be easier to manage.

Launch your cron on startup,
At each tick your cron read a task queues
If you consider that the task is done remove it or update it to done

In the other hand, build your UI to add / remove / update tasks in the queue

```
var job = new CronJob({
    cronTime : '0 0 * * * *',
    onTick   : function(){
        Task_Model.find({done: 0})
        .sort({priority: 1})
        .exec(function(err, tasks){
            if(!err && tasks)
            {
               tasks.forEach(function(e, i, r){
                   myFunctionToExecuteTask(e, function(err, done){

                   })
                });
            }
         });
        },
    onComplete:function(){
        console.log("[APPCRON] CRON 1H - finished")
    },
    start    : true,
    runOnInit: true
});
```